# Help needed on contains()

Tags: jquery

Here is the HTML code of a radio button

```
<input type="radio" class="grgrgrtgxxxxfeegrgbrg">
```

I am trying to check whether radio button's name is having xx.
Here is my jquery code i have written

```
if($(this).prop('class').contains('xxxx'))
                               {
                                 alert("Yup");
                               }
```

Please tell me the Syntax mistake in it.

Comment: Why don't you use .hasClass() instead?

Comment: `prop` does not return a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contains` is a jQuery method that works with elements not with strings so you must use string methods:

```
if($(this).prop('class').indexOf("xx")>-1)
{
    alert("Yup");
}
```

But as someone else said you can use hasClass:

```
if($(this).hasClass("xx")) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`contains` isn't a method of strings in JavaScript. Since from your question you really do want substring matching in the middle of a class name, you can use `indexOf`:

```
if ($(this).prop('class').indexOf('xx') >= 0)
{
    alert("Yup");
}
```

Note that you don't need jQuery for this at all, just use the [reflected property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95362176) of the DOM element:

```
if (this.className.indexOf('xx') >= 0)
{
    alert("Yup");
}
```

`className` reflects the `"class"` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
var className = $(this).attr('class');
int i = className.IndexOf("xx");"
if(i > -1)
{alert("has the xx class");}
```

Comment: he wants to check if the given element has that class if yes then alert the above piece of code does the same my friend, the index of portion i snot included since others have already did that, so that would complete the answer, just for help and simplicity i posted my answer

Comment: no the OP wants to check whether the class contains/have a specific text string, see the answers below for clarification